# Failed to Send Host log on ERROR

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

[image]I know that there are similiar questions , but none of them seems to resolve the Issue. Basically, a quite few days back, there was this notification coming on my ubuntu VM that there is a little root disk space left.But, now when I am trying to open my Ubuntu on Virtual Box, I am getting the following error ERROR: failed to send host log me,in black screen. I think it is due to the less root disk space notification which was showing earlier.

Any help on fixing this will really be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].